# Anaconda Spyder doesn't show the program window on windows 10--tried c:\spyder reset

Tags: anaconda

Windows 10, Python 3.5, have been using spyder for a while. 
Now spyder starts, window shows in the task bar, but not on the screen.
Recently changed my background window. Changed back, but doesn't help.
No problem with other applications.

I closed spyder and restarted with C:\spyder reset.
Problem still here.

Comment: Solved my own problem: Went to c:\users\me\docs and settings\.spyder2-py3 and renamed spyder.ini (to anything); then restarted spyder, and it recreated the spyder.ini file.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem but I managed to solve it by executing this command in Anaconda Prompt.
So, you need to run Anaconda Prompt (instead of Command Prompt) and execute this command:

spyder --reset

It worked for me and I hope it will work for you as well.

Comment: This works, but there is a better method that doesn't wipeout all user preferences. See my answer below.

Comment: Indeed, and I'd even use @Eztaban solution below which is a more straightforward fix for the causes described by Colton Campbell

Answer (score 8):

I got the same problem. And solved it with the recomendations of this link -> https://www.njevity.com/2014/02/18/a-window-is-not-visible-how-to-move-off-screen-windows-back-into-view/

Basically:

- select the icon in your taskbar/ alt + tab to select
- hit Alt+Space+M
- your mouse icon turns into a cross with arrows
- use the direction keys to move the screen around, with this you get the spyder window back in place

Comment: This is the solution if your Spyder window has moved off to a display that you can't see (and may not exist).

Answer (score 4):

***Although this question is old, it is still a problem with current (5.4.2) Spyder.***

### The Root Cause

The issue is that if you have Spyder open on an external monitor, then close Spyder and later remove that monitor, next launch Spyder will try and open on that missing monitor. Hence, the icon will show in the taskbar but no window will appear. You can confirm Spyder is running by activating the icon in the taskbar then hitting `F11` to Fullscreen the Spyder window; it will then show.

##### The Unsatisfactory Fix

I have seen the other answers stating that you can either use `spyder --reset` from the CLI or you can do the Fullscreen trick and do `Tools > Reset Spyder to Factory Defaults`, but I didn't want to lose my configuration settings.

### A Better Option to Fix

Instead of wiping out your preferences, you can navigate to your preference file located (on Windows/MacOS) in `~/.spyder-py3/config/spyder.ini` where `~` is the User Folder. Using a text editor, change the line that says `window/is_maximized = False` to `True`. Save the .ini file, and re-launch Spyder; the window should appear maximized on one of your monitors now.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple fix, that does not force full screen, reset, or crash anything:**

Old question i know, but still happens.
A fix is expected in Spyder 6. The issue is related to changing monitors as described by [Colton Campbell.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75593507/19061111) 
For now, it should work to select a different application, snap it somewhere on your desktop to one side. Assuming you are running on Windows, you will then be able to select what application to snap to the other part of the screen. 
Here it should be possible to select Spyder. Once it is selected, it should be back to normal operation.

I have not tested on linux or mac.

The explanation can be found on the spyde github:
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/20344

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar issue, where spyder shows up in the taskbar but doesnt appear on the main screen. I encountered this after connecting to an external monitor. Solved this using (Windows): Win-key + Z -> Chose the two-column template, and spyder appears in the second column once you choose from it.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this too. I would run Anaconda, launch Spyder, and on my Windows 10 HP laptop, the Spyder icon would appear at the bottom, but I would not see any Spyder window. The launch progress bar would show, and the window with the Spyder logo version 4 would temporarily show up during the launch sequence, but that was the end of it. No Spyder window.

It turns out that because I had been using a second monitor earlier, the Spyder IDE window was launching into this second monitor, even though it was no longer attached. If you were using a second monitor and now do not see Spyder showing up, reconnect the second monitor and see if it is there then. I hope that this helps. I have sent this in as a bug to Spyder and they will contact me about it.

Comment: I had the same problem. However I did not have the second monitor available any more. For me, I could select the Spyder icon in the task bar and then press F11 to enter full screen mode. From there I could press the "Tools" button and press "Reset Spyder to factory defaults"

Comment: Pressing F11 worked for me to show the Spyder window, but I don't want to reset Spyder to factory defaults because I've changed a bunch of preferences.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't want to reset Spyder because it would waste time redoing all my preferences (if resetting does indeed reset those preferences, I couldn't confirm that).

I closed and restarted Spyder via the (in my case) miniforge prompt, but it didn't fix the problem; that is, Spyder opened, but was still only visible if set to fullscreen.

Going to the **File item in the menubar and clicking Restart** (Alt+Shift+R) restored Spyder to a usable condition.

However, it actually crashed Python completely and maybe Spyder unusable.  So then I closed Spyder and closed my console, then reopened the console and started Spyder again, and then everything worked normally.

Answer (score 0):

Hover over the Spyder icon in the task bar until the small window view appears. Move over the small window view and right click.  Select Maximize from the menu and Spyder will  maximize into one of the current monitor windows.